# Multiple Visual studio projects (one solution) in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, visual-studio-2019, visual-sourcesafe, multiple-projects

I am bit new to Git/GitLab. We are moving from Visual Source safe(VSS) to  GitLab.
We have a Visual studio solutions with multiple projects(20 to 25). It was easy to create repository structure in VSS as individual projects.

How does it work with Git/GitLab. Can I create individual repositories in Git/GitLab and then pull them to make a solution. How do Commit, Push work?

I tested with 1 single solution containing 2 projects, but since the projects are in different repositories, I have to toggle the main branch for each commit for respective projects.

How can Git/GitLab support one solution with multiple projects where each project having separate repository.

Thank you for your help
Babu

Answer (score 0):

VS 2022 has support for projects in different repositories in the same solution.
It's still a preview feature so you'll need to turn it on. So far it works great for push and pull however I'd like to see a more graceful clone from other repos that are referenced. More information here:
[Multi-repo Support in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repo-support-in-visual-studio/)